# Access denied to Windows partition on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: restricted-access

I have installed Ubuntu 17.04 dual boot with Windows 10. Now I can't write data to my local disks from Ubuntu. I have only read access. Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

While in Windows:

Open Command prompt which you find in All Programs > Accessories (right click and left click run as admin) and type : powercfg -h off

Restart into Ubuntu and you should be good to go. You will lose the hibernate ability but now can access the disk and read and write to it.

hope that helps...

If not, use "sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2 or 3 or 5" according to the error specified